# Should I hide certain education history on my CV/resume?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, masters, industry, abuse

Apologize in advance if it is not suitable for this site. I consider asking this in workplace exchange, but I think people on this site are more familiar with similar situation. For obvious reasons I open a new account to keep myself anonymous.

I am a last year Ph.D. student that will almost exclusively apply for industry jobs in the near future, and I have earned a master degree during my 2nd year in the program (FYI: In US people in Ph.D. program sometime obtain a master degree in the middle of the process, after passing some requirements). In other words, if I finish Ph.D. in the current program I will have a bachelor degree, a master degree and a Ph.D. degree just from the current institution and my undergraduate institution.

Many years ago, before entering the current program, I had another master degree in a different field that is the product of Ph.D. drop out (where, at least from my point of view, is due to getting abused/bullied. I burned the bridge on my way out, due to my attempt to report & confront.).

In this situation, does it make sense to omit that master degree on my resume, given that it looks somewhat weird and in most cases unrelated to the jobs I apply for right now and in the near future? The only reason I still include it is to seal the time gap on the resume, but I am afraid there is a little risk of people asking for references from the program I dropped out from (on my transcript it is stated PhD: discontinued). I am not sure if omitting and (if necessary) explaining the time gap could be a better strategy for the purpose of industry job applications than including and (if necessary) explaining the switch field (I'm not worry about explaining why new program fit my goal better, but worry about getting bad references).

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: I'd say omit it. Every job application requires that you create a specific CV for that role. Otherwise you would have one CV only and mass spam all places. And the key phrase here is that the unfinished phd was "unrelated to the jobs I apply for".